# Ordering columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've got a table, `products` with dimensions like this:

```
+------------+--------+-------+--------+
| product_id | length | width | height |
+------------+--------+-------+--------+
|          1 |  23.00 | 25.00 |  22.00 |
|          2 |  14.25 | 14.25 |   1.75 |
|          3 |  19.50 |  3.00 |   2.50 |
|          4 |   3.50 | 11.00 |  19.00 |
+------------+--------+-------+--------+
```

What I need to do is put them in order so `length` is always the greatest dimension, `width` is second greatest, and `height` is smallest.  It's easy enough to this:

```
SELECT
    GREATEST(length,width,height) AS length,
    LEAST(length,width,height) AS height
FROM products
```

But how can I can the final dimension?  Then I tried this:

```
SELECT product_id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(dim ORDER BY dim DESC), ',', 1) AS length,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(dim ORDER BY dim DESC), ',', 2), ',', -1) AS width,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(dim ORDER BY dim DESC), ',', -1) AS height 
FROM
(
    SELECT product_id, length AS dim
    FROM products
    UNION
    SELECT product_id, width AS dim
    FROM products
    UNION
    SELECT product_id, height AS dim
    FROM products
) v
GROUP BY product_id;
```

This actually works, but seems absurdly complicated.  Can anyone suggest a simpler solution that will perform better than what I've outlined above?

Comment: Actually, I think that's how I'd do this.

Comment: lol - it seems like such an easy thing and in most other languages you'd just sort the array - but in sql I'm a bit stumped at how to eloquently solve this.  the thing I did here feels really hacky

Comment: Use find_in_set() instead of SUBSTRING_INDEX(), that's a lot easier to handle, particularly if you have more than 3 columns to order.

Comment: @Shadow - can you give an example of how to use `find_in_set()` with `group_concat()` or with my query above?  I'm just getting an error trying it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some simple math will do it, given there's only 3 columns:

```
SELECT length + width + height 
     - GREATEST(length, width, height) 
     - LEAST(length, width, height) AS width
FROM products
```

For more than a fixed set of columns, you are basically unpivoting then pivoting. Some db's have a nonstandard extension like UNPIVOT/PIVOT in T-SQL, but I don't there's an easy to do that in MySQL that doesn't end up looking like your query, or a morally equivalent using `listagg`.

Comment: good idea :-)  I'm interested in an ordering solution that will work for 4 or more columns as well, but this does indeed solve the question in a better way than what I did.  thanks

Comment: that's a more complicated answer, since you want basically do pivoting operations, which aren't really easy in MySQL